# Mysql select row that contains max value with conditions

Tags: mysql

I would like to select the row that contains the max value on a column (rank) with specific conditions:

1. result > 0
2. apply = 17

[image]

this is my sql select

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE apply = 17 and result > 0
HAVING MAX(rank)
```

In this exapmle i should have as output the row with id 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not aggregating here so *having* is not correct; you want a single row based on an order (by rank) so

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE apply = 17 and result > 0
ORDER BY rank DESC
LIMIT 1;
```